# Wondering in C strings, NULL, white spaces

Tags: c, string, whitespace

In C, can I say a white space in a string has a NULL type, or something else?
In C, which character represents the termination of a string?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (ASCII value 0, `'\0'` as a character literal) terminates a string in C. This character is *not* usually regarded as a whitespace character.

The space in the middle of this string for example: `"Hello world"` is the character with ASCII value 32. This is not the same as NULL or `\0`.

Comment: In fact the name of the ASCII character that terminates a string is NUL

Comment: I think there is no need for "usally". Checking the standard I read that in the "C" locale only whitespace characters return `true`; for other locales the standard says "The isspace function tests for any character that is a standard white-space character or is one of a locale-specific set of characters for which isalnum is false". The `NUL` character is however part of the basic execution character set (this is also stated explicitly) and cannot therefore be one of the locale-specific set of characters cited.

Answer (score 3):

> In C, can I say a white space in a
>   string has a NULL type, or something
>   else?

I'm not sure what you mean by a NULL type. A white space is a space character or tab or carriage return.

> In C, which character represents
>   the termination of a string?

The `'\0'` character is the termination of a string.

Answer (score 3):

The following characters are regarded as "whitespace" in the sense that the  isspace() function returns non-zero:

- space (ASCII 0x32, C literal `' '`)
- tab (ASCII 0x09, C literal `'\t'`)
- vertical tab (ASCII 0x0B, C literal `'\v'`)
- form feed (ASCII 0x0C, C literal `'\f'`)
- carriage return (ASCII 0x0E, C literal `'\r'`)
- newline (ASCII 0x0A, C literal `'\n'`)

The string terminator is the ASCII NUL (0x00) character; it generally has no effect on the cursor if you attempt to output it to a console or terminal.

Comment: Trivia: NUL is coded as zero because it corresponds to blank paper tape leader. DEL is coded as 0x7f (or 0xff sometimes) because it corresponds to all holes punched on a paper tape, and it used to be called RUBOUT indicating that it was used to correct mistakes without requiring that an operator repunch an entire tape.

Answer (score 0):

The termination character is a byte with value 0. Expressed as a literal character, it is `'\0'`.

Your first question about white space having a NULL type doesn't make any sense.